# How do I use my model to predict new cases?

Tags: classification, predictive-models

I mainly use spss modeler but I don't think it has the functionality to use a generated model to predict the group new unseen cases belong to (one of two). It seems like it would need to be done manually?

I was wondering if it's possible in R? For instance, after splitting my data into training and test, I want to create some predictive models such as random forest, logistic regression etc. using the training set and then use those generated models to predict the test data set.

I found some material online for predicting using Weka but have not used it before and can't seem to find a (safe) place to download it from. However I have only basic skills in R so if it would be better to use Weka, can someone provide me with the link to downloading the tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use that tool, but it'd be pretty silly if a model building tool didn't have an easy mechanism to score new data. It will just be a matter of finding out how to do it in whatever tool you're most comfortable with. For SPSS I found this: [Applying SPSS Models](https://youtu.be/eboTREc3uSk)